# reshape data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
variable=c("alpha","beta1","beta2")
value=c(22,11,33)

df=data.frame(variable=variable,
              value=value)

df

variable value
alpha    22
beta1    11
beta2    33
```

and I would like it to look like this:

```
coef   alpha  beta1  beta2
value   22    11      33
```

what is the reshape/cast/dcast logic?

thank you

Comment: There is a `t.data.frame` function. Did you try that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
(d <- dcast(df, 'value' ~ variable, value.var='value'))
```

However, to get the name of you first column right you will still need to do

```
names(d)[1] <- "coef"
```

don't know if its possible to do this in one statement.